# WF: === Starting > WebFilter logging for process warning when establishing WKWebview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, wkwebview

I realise that there have been a lot of posts on this subject but I can't seem to find any solution relevant to my circumstances. I also realise that I can just disable the warnings but that does not get to the cause of why they are happening.

I am using XCode 11.3.1 and I get the following warning:

> 2020-05-11 18:05:50.416785+0100 xxx[2236:589704] WF: === Starting
>   WebFilter logging for process xxx
>
> 2020-05-11 18:05:50.416825+0100 xxx[2236:589704] WF:
>   _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
>       filterBlacklist =     (
>       );
>       filterWhitelist =     (
>       );
>       restrictWeb = 1;
>       useContentFilter = 0;
>       useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
>       whitelistEnabled = 0; }
>
> 2020-05-11 18:05:50.416867+0100 xxx[2236:589704] WF:
>   _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO

when a WKWebview is established in a view. For example:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *WKConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKTextView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:WKConfiguration];
WKTextView.navigationDelegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:WKTextView];
```

I have read that it is related to referencing http://xxx but I only use https. Does anyone have an explanation as to why this warning is appearing?